# Assistance required playing a looping video in a window without controls

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, video

I've been able to play a video full screen, but when I try and play it in a window (on an iPad) the video controls just show it as loading all the time.

What I want to do is automatically play and loop the video as soon as viewDidLoad is called.

Here's my code so far..

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 pathForResource:@"Test"
                 ofType:@"mp4"];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
 initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(500, 400, 200, 200);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];

//---play movie---

[player.moviePlayer play];
player = nil;
```

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found this works if you put the player.play statement into viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution, but here's what worked for me:

Create a `UIView` to use as a container for the video and give it the size you want your video to be. Even though you'll be setting the view's frame, it seems you still need to set the `movieplayer`'s frame as well.

Then you just need a few additional modifiers on your player.

```
UIView *movieView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 400, 200, 200)];

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 253, 175);
player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

[self.view addSubview:movieView];

[movieView addSubview:mpviewController.view];
```

Without setting the controls to `MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded` the controls will show up huge. Bigger than the actual video at 200 x 200. `MPMovieControlStyleHidden` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I made a UIView subclass that does exactly this. Check it out here: http://github.com/liaujianjie/VideoLoopView

**Code:**

```
self.videoView.videoUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"samplevideo.mov" withExtension:nil];
```